# Modal logic equivalent to two-variable first-order logic?

Tags: first-order-logic

It is well-known that many modal logics can be viewed as fragments of $FO^2$, i.e. two-variable first-order logic.

But is there a modal logic that is not a fragment, but is expressively equivalent to $FO^2$?